# Can I use .ajaxSend to modify ajax options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What's the difference between `.ajaxPrefilter` and `.ajaxSend` when they are both used in modifying request settings?

I have used `.ajaxSend` to change the values of ajax options. The reason I doing this is that there is a `.ajaxPrefilter` function in library file, and I have to change the value of some option(Obviously, I can not modify the library file). If I use `.ajaxPrefilter` in my file, it executes before the one in library file. So the value will be reset in library file.

In the end I use `.ajaxSend` in my own file to make it happen.

Is it right to use `.ajaxSend` like this?

Ref:

[.ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/)

[.ajaxSend](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/)

Comment: Turns out that .ajaxSend can not modify ajax options. We can use beforeSend method in .ajaxSetup to modify options in the last minute. But it can not delete any options.